# ckeditor click event does not work

Tags: ckeditor

I have a ckeditor plugin and inside the init: I want to capture the click event so I can do something.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('Columns',{
  init : function(editor) {
    editor.on('doubleclick', function(ev) {console.log('hello');}); // Works
    editor.on('focus', function(ev) {console.log('hello');}); // Works

    editor.on('click', function(ev) {console.log('hello');}); // Does not work
    editor.on('mousedown', function(ev) {console.log('hello');}); // Does not work
  }
});
```

Any Ideas???

**EDIT:**
OK could not get click working, I believe we need to create an event for that. However thanks to this post: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html

I managed to use 'saveSnapshot' which seems to fire each time I click so this now works

```
editor.on('saveSnapshot', function(ev) {console.log('hello');}); // Works
```

Comment: Try `editor.editable().on( 'click', callback )` instead.

Comment: `editor.editable()` requires an argument. I have found that `editor.editable(editor.element)` works for inlined editors, but breaks for normal editors.

Comment: Correction. `editor.editable()` works, but you can only call it after the editor fires the `instanceReady` event.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is old but it doesn't have an answer to the original question.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('Columns',{
    init : function(editor) {
        editor.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
            this.container.on('click', function (event) {
                console.log('hello');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**Note**: this won't work when CKEditor is in 'classic iframe mode'. Instead, you'll need to use `this.document` (see: [document property](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-document)) to get a reference to the iframe.

Comment: The event fires for clicks outside the editor when we use this approach. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Af6KD/

Comment: @F21 When not in iframe mode `this.document` gets a reference to the whole page document, try using `this.container` instead (see edit)

Comment: Thanks, this worked :) Yet more ckeditor stuff that I have to find the info by digging up forums/posts.. what a piece of ****!